# Composer Deployment of Airflow not recruiting available workers

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer, airflow-celery

I've created a data pipeline through Airflow and deployed on Google Composer (composer-2.0.32-airflow-2.3.4).

The bulk of the work in the pipeline is data analysis and occurs through Python Operators. Details of the airflow environment workloads configuration are below:

```
Scheduler: 4 vCPUs, 16 GB memory, 5 GB storage
Number of schedulers: 10
Triggerer: 2 vCPUs, 4 GB memory, 1 GB storage
Web server: 2 vCPUs, 8 GB memory, 5 GB storage
Worker: 2 vCPUs, 8 GB memory, 5 GB storage
Number of workers: Autoscaling between 4 and 64 workers
```

The issue that I'm having is that Airflow never exceeds 4 workers even though the DAGs are running slow relative to my machine. For context, an individual DAG can take up to a minute to run on Airflow compared to less than a second on my machine, which is a basic MacBook Pro. This is of course because more tasks are running in parallel on Airflow, which is why I'd like to recruit more resources.

I increased the minimum number of workers to 16 just to test speed improvements, and the performance improved as expected, but again it never recruited more than 16 and still took longer than what I think should be possible if it recruited what should be available.

I'm not sure if I'm just misunderstanding the function of workers or how the auto scaling works here, so any clarification or help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud composer autoscaling is based on Airflow configurations and the number of tasks in the queue that are not assigned to a worker (queued tasks).

So check what is the value used for `celery.worker_concurrency` (the max number of parallel tasks running on a worker), `celery.worker_autoscale` (the same idea but it Airflow choose between provided max and min values and the number of the available workers), and `core.parallelism` (the maximum number of task instances that can run concurrently per scheduler).

The number of total running tasks is `core.parallelism` * the number of scheduler (10 in your case), if it's the default value (32), you will have 320 running tasks maximum in the server. And each worker will run `celery.worker_concurrency` of this tasks, if it's 128 for example, the 4 workers could run 4*128 tasks = 512 tasks > 320. In this case you will not have queued tasks in the queue and the autoscaler will do nothing, but the tasks will share the resources of 1 worker (2 cpus for 128 tasks), and you will have some performance issues.